# load balancing mssql using dns + replication

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to use 3 dedicated servers with mssql 2012 installed to load balance queries in order that the database does not get bogged down with too many queries.

There will only be one database which will be around 10GB to start with but will definitely grow over time.

I am guessing for the load balancing part I can use a dns name in my connection like sql.domain.com and when a connection is made, the dns will decide which server ip to serve or I could randomly choose an ip within the connection?

My main part of the question is though: how do I get the three databases replicating each other so that if one person connects to sql server 1, the same data is written to the other sql servers?

All 3 databases must be exact replicas of each other.

Am I needing clustering or replication or??

Answer (score 0):

Using AlwaysOn Availability Groups you can set-up read-only replicas. You need to create a Windows Failover Cluster. On each of the cluster nodes install SQL Server 2012. For simple load balancing you can create a SQL Server listener which will direct Read Intent queries to the read only database.